# what happens when mount a partition on /?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, mount, mountpoint

I have a partition `/dev/sdb1` what happens after executing this command?

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 / -o rw
                     ^
```

I know that must change mountpoint "/" address as mentioned above.
When I type this in my terminal. The command is executed but after some minutes my laptop will freeze.
I want to know what happens?

Comment: / means [root](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/images/FS-layout.png) of file-system, its start point of [FSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard), it is the point where your file-system is mounted. Your command remounts /(root) with some /dev/sda1. So system freezes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/`, which is the base directory of the Linux filesystem and is normally where the partition on which you installed Ubuntu is mounted, was changed to be the mountpoint of sdb1. Because of this, files critical to Linux suddenly disappeared, causing your computer to freeze. All your files are still there, but since the drive that `/` was pointing to suddenly changed, Linux couldn't find them anymore.